# i am getting error " Keyword not supported: '(local);initial catalog'."

Tags: c#-4.0

```
public static string getconnection()
{
    //string db1 = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "CheckExe.accdb";
    //string Connection"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=|DataDirectory|\\CheckExe.accdb";
    string Connection = "(local);Initial Catalog=School_Sharda;Integrated Security=True";
    return Connection;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `Date Source` key:

```
string Connection = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=School_Sharda;Integrated Security=True";
```

Comment: but this time i m getting error again is "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

Comment: @KapilKaushal: That means that the syntax of the connection string is correct as it goes on to actually trying to connect. The connection failed, either because you are trying to access a named instance without the name, or because the database server needs to be configured for that kind of connection.